# iPad web app: How to trigger full screen video on first play?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, ipad, video

I embedded a video which needs to play full screen on click.

I was able to bind the full screen instruction to the play button of the controls, but not to the play button which is shown first.

Which event do I need to bind it to?

Here are the important pieces of my code. (I use jquery.)

```
<video id="vid1" width="200" height="122" poster="files-11/video1-200x122.jpg" controls>
    <source src="/path-to/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

```js
$("#vid1").bind('play',function() {
    $("#vid1")[0].webkitEnterFullScreen();
});
```

Comment: I just replaced 'play' with 'playing' and it works. However, I am not sure if this is a clean solution. I am open for better solutions, if there are any.

Comment: I wasn't aware this was possible and I can't imagine there being a better solution.